# Why total_count in friendlist is different from actual number of friends count from facebook graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get friendlist from facebook:

```
$send_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=CAATihlnybnYBALlxCHkgcnVxQ7HvZAyPYqBMWHtBfdLizNZBzIffMBFBfVBzZCDCvOXuZBzbTDcRd36xfwwtSghQBM6rZB14bL4FjhHRcX0ZAIYt3oi3ShbqAEU4aXZAjHD4MtYSQmHsq8RR0uEz4ZBfk2hD1GLctLZAzifTcQGwg26D0AQZBBvD1FkEFgUWhu1YaXZCwTojHwe4AZDZD";
```

Then I count the friends by:

```
    $jsonFriends = json_decode($data, true);
$friendsLists = $jsonFriends['data'];
$i=0;
foreach ($friendsLists as $friends) 
{
  $i=$i+1;
}
echo $i;
```

I got $i which is number of friends is : 453, however if the access_token expire, I don't get the data but it still give the summary with total_count is 474.
So I wondering what is the meaning of 474 ? Is this the total number of friends (I check on my facebook page, All friends, and the number also 474). Then why my count give the different number ? I am quite confident with the counting, as I give a shorter test data and I can double check it and see it counts correctly.

Comment: They may have blocked you or blocked Facebook Platform. Or deleted their accounts

Comment: How could the difference so large ? I don't think there are 21 (474-453) people block or deleted their Fb

Comment: I believe it could be that big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends) for /{user-id}/friends states that:

> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login)    the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

This probably explains why you the count of people returned in the `data` object is different from `total_count`:

```
"summary": {
    "total_count": 474
  }
```

which returns the total number of Facebook friends regardless of whether they have the app or not.
This probably accounts for the 21 people missing in your list.

Comment: That could be true! But in this case, the number of friends already used this app like that is more than I expected ! :D Tk u for your answer ! :)